# jQuery: Get clicked anchor from within unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this markup (simplified):

```
<ul class="targets">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="info">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="info">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="info">C</a></li>
</ul>
```

And this script (simplified):

```
$('.targets').click(function(e) {
    alert(e.target); // alerts "javascript:void(0);"
});
```

What I really want is the clicked anchor object, not the target for the anchor.

If this is possible, how do I do it?

It must be anchors in the list, but the function must handle clicks on other dom elements as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your confusion comes from the `e.target` toString being the `href` property, for example:

```
$('.targets').click(function(e) {
  alert(e.target.nodeName); // alerts "A"
  $(e.target).fadeOut();    //this would fade out the anchor you clicked on
})​;
```

`e.target` **is** what you already have, you just need to access whatever property you're interested in on it.  Otherwise when you alert it, by default it shows the `href` property.

[Here's a demo to see what I mean](http://jsfiddle.net/cmycn/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.targets li a.info').click(function(e) {
    alert(this);     // alerts the anchor DOM object itself
    alert(e.target); // alerts "javascript:void(0);" <- this *should* do the same
});
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, It has to work with other elements than anchors as well. Is it possible?

Comment: @Mickel: Sure, it works with any element that you bind the function to. Instead of working with `e.target`, use `this` directly, as indicated.

Answer (score 0):

It's not doing what you think it's doing; `e.target` is definitely your `<a>` element. Try changing it to `alert(e.target.className)` to prove it to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.targets li a').click(function(e) {
    alert(this.attr('href'));
});
```

the keyword "this" as a jQuery reference to the element at hand